# How to specify radius for "MeanShift" Method of FindClusters

Tags: options, cluster-analysis

I would like to specify the radius used for the `"MeanShift"` `Method` of `FindClusters`.  Where in the documentation can this information be found?

For a minimal example.

```
SeedRandom[123];
dis = MixtureDistribution[{1, 1, 1, 1}, {
    MultinormalDistribution[{-1, -3}, {{.5, 0}, {0, .5}}],
    MultinormalDistribution[{-3, 1}, {{.5, 0}, {0, .5}}],
    MultinormalDistribution[{1, 4}, {{.5, 0}, {0, .5}}], 
    MultinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, {{.5, 0}, {0, .5}}]}];
data = RandomVariate[dis, 500];
ListPlot[data, PlotRange -> All]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ListPlot[FindClusters[data, Method -> "MeanShift"]]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

I want to tweak the radius such that it returns 4 clusters.  I know I can use the `"KMeans"` method with a target of 4 clusters but I can't pre-select the clusters in all instances.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ListPlot[clusters = 
  FindClusters[data, 
   Method -> {"MeanShift", "NeighborhoodRadius" -> 0.5}]]
```

[image]

```
Length @ clusters
```

> 4

Comment: I saw `"NeighborhoodRadius"` as an additional option for `"NeighborhoodContraction"`.  Did you just try and see or is there somewhere in the documentation that further options are given for `Method` options?

Comment: I saw it exactly there, and just tried it and it appears to work.

Comment: Documentation needs some work on this function.